# Is possible to use ffmpeg to capture directly a DSLR streaming via USB?

Tags: ffmpeg, dslr, video-capture

If i have an high end Canon or Nikon camera is possible to do what [eos_movrec](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eos-movrec/) do but with a better quality? Could be useful to use this for streaming or recording purposes.

And in case of something available, is also possible to tune the config on the fly?

Comment: This reply - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31174822 - shows a way to do it with some Sony cameras.

Comment: @Mulvya The Problem with that answer is that rely on the fact that Sony Cameras have an api and a streaming server ready to give you a stream of Motion JPG sequence. Then, the thing you do with ffmpeg is grab that stream and do something else with it. I would like doing this with Canon Cameras DLSR like a 5D Mark II or 5D Mark III. Would be very cool for all the Video Production community to find a solution for it ;)

Comment: How about this one - http://digicamcontrol.com/feature-list

Comment: @Mulvya indeed is a software I'm actually testing, it gives you a streamserver on http://127.0.0.1:5513/liveview.html?CMD=LiveViewWnd_Show , the stream resource looks like a jpg file that follows with a random number in the back in order to prevent the caching. There's a way ffmpeg can grab this "stream of data" and transcode, restream or whatever? Would be cool have many answer on this discussion with each possible alternative, in order to leave something very informative for people with the same needings.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture a live-view feed from your USB-connected Canon DSLR with gphoto2 (param: --capture-movie). The biggest limitation here is that the resulting mjpeg stream resolution is 1056x704, and that's the highest possible quality via USB. This mjpeg stream can be piped to ffmpeg. As an alternative, you could get yourself an USB<>Mini-HDMI recording dongle (e.g. "Elgato Cam Link"), this will give you a FullHD (1920x1080) resolution and you can use your Canon DSLR like any USB webcam, which can also be piped to ffmpeg.

Comment: I only get between 4 and 5 fps with gphoto2, from my Canon EOS 100D. I suppose that the resolution is too high, but cannot find how to reduce it from gphoto2!